# Apache 413 Entity to Large

Tags: apache, tomcat, railo

Environment:

windows 2008 R2
Apache 2.2.27
Tomcat 7.0.45
Railo 3.3.3

The application is passing in a URL string of 4000 + characters. Apache is giving us a "Entity Too Large" 413 error message. I can confirmed that it is the URL length (when I reduce the query string parameters the page works fine).

I have attempted to use the limitrequestline and limitrequestfieldsize directives and when the URL length is more than 4000 the directive "Seems" to be ignored. However if I set the LimitRequestLine low, a 414 error occurs.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Dan

Comment: This may help http://serverfault.com/questions/402630/http-error-413-request-entity-too-large. Also, as per Apache, "If the request size sent by the client exceeds the maximum size allocated by this directive, the server will return 413 Request Entity Too Large."

Comment: Anit - thanks for the link. That is one of the articles I read when researching the issue. The directive SecRequestBodyAccess  is for mod_security, which we do not currently have implemented.

Comment: Not an answer but if you are passing such large strings in the URL you are breaking the spec and maybe should try a form post instead.

Comment: Understood, have a query string this large is really bad form. Unfortunately the rev work required to make the change is pretty significant. Hoping to solve via apache confit change for the short term.

Comment: The default `LimitRequestLine` is 8190 bytes. Are you sending more than that? Response 413 is Request *Entity* Too Large. The *entity* is the body of the request, not the URL in the request line. So you are sending a huge URL *and* a huge body, evidently.